# After successful generation of access token using oauth2.0 upload file/folder to onedrive/sharepoint in Webapplication

Tags: c#, sharepoint, onedrive

Using Oauth 2.0 i have authorized the user, got the access token and refresh token, using access token how to upload file to one drive

Comment: Due lack of information provided (Technologies used and so on), i will give it a shot in the dark: have a look at this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-upload-file-to-21125137/sourcecode?fileId=158961&pathId=1503686119  OR MS Graph => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822779/upload-new-file-to-onedrive-using-microsoft-graph-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: I am using c# ,web core api 2.0 using MS Graph to upload file/download to/from one drive and sharepoint. I am looking for sample to upload file/download to/from one drive and sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

There is a LOT of official documentation about this topic.

This is the documentation for [Downloading a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online)
where you could take a look at:

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content
GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
GET /users/{userId}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

and [this is for Uploading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online)

**HTTP request (to replace an existing item)**

```
PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
PUT /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
PUT /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
PUT /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

**HTTP request (to upload a new file)**
HTTP

```
PUT /drives/{drive-id}/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /me/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
PUT /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

Also here is the [documentation about Drives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/drive?view=odsp-graph-online) and [DriveItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem?view=odsp-graph-online)

Comment: Thanks , but issue is when trying to call these api, returning error "unauhtneticate token ". Now i am trying using :- var uploadedFileOnedrive = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(fileName).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream); its working for creating file on root for one drive but i need to create file inside particular folder. Also need to Create file to Sharepoint.

Comment: Than we need more code in order to provide any decent help. Show us how you are requesting your Token to start, but provide any code that can help us help you.